# Why should I sync my Google account in Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, online-accounts

I can see that in Ubuntu 15.10 (and previous versions, such as Ubuntu 14.04 stable) there is an option in the configuration menu: *Online accounts*

I can add my Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Jabber, etc. accounts.

I'm interested in adding Google, but I don't know why should I sync it. What integration features will I gain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syncing the Google account improves convenience.

Main advantage is the Ubuntu system integration.

Which services will be synced with the system ?

Contacts : Google contacts

Google Drive : File search

Empathy : Chat contacts

Thunderbird : Mail conversations

Thunderbird Lightning : Google calendar

[image]

Comment: Do I have to configure Thunderbird after syncing an online account?

Comment: You only have to configure Thunderbird Lightning to additionally use the Google Calendar. :)